# What do you call someone who worked in IT?

Tags: resume, title, position

I'm arranging my resume so skills that belong together fall under the same heading. For example

> **Development**
>
> - created easy to navigate websites using jQuery UI
> - carefully wrote test cases for each functional unit
> - etc.

What do you call the position who does IT related work? In these positions I often supported the developers and worked lots with VMware. Also various miscellaneous problems with various programs (such as end users firewall not turning on) was another of my responsibilities.

> **IT**
>
> - managed virtual provisioning using vSphere client
> - fixed problems with various end user programs, such as firewalls
> - configured RAID for an optimal balance between speed and redundancy
> - etc.

having the heading "IT" looks silly here, what is another name? I don't think dev ops is quit the right fit.

Comment: I'd call that a system operator (sysop) role.

Comment: In your first list, the "configured RAID" part doesn't fit (maybe should be in your second list). I don't think that is a software development activity, unless you wrote software to do that.

Comment: "System Engineer" is fairly common (for example, an MCSE is a Microsoft Certified System Engineer), although the RAID config job falls in this category and not in that of a developer.  ("Network Engineer" is another term.)  A developer develops applications, a system engineer keeps the hardware and software that run the applications in working order.  IT encompasses both roles.

Comment: How do you see RAID as development?

Comment: But you need the proper accreditation to be called an engineer @BobRodes

Comment: @JustDoIt While I find many statements--yours being an example--to that effect, I haven't been able to find any legal requirement in the US to have any sort of official license or accreditation to call yourself a "software engineer" or "system/network engineer." If you can point me to documentation--meaning actual statutes--to the contrary I would be interested to see it.

Comment: Each state has its own specifics regarding licensing in engineering, In all the states I've lived so far you need to at least be accredited from a ABET accredited curriculum program in order to at least call yourself a graduate engineer(A non licensed engineer). @BobRodes I looked it up cause I had to live in those states, but it's not my onus to do that research for you.

Comment: @JustDoIt I'm sorry, but if you are making an assertion that evidence exists that contravenes my position, I'm afraid the *onus probandi* is yours.  The default position is mine, that no such evidence exists.  As for your "graduate engineer", that's a different term, as is "professional engineer", for which I've found ample evidence of licensing requirements.  I've looked for, and can't find, any legal requirement for a license to call yourself a software, system or network engineer.

Comment: [PE test for software engineers](https://cdn.ncees.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/SWE-Apr-2013.pdf) started being offered spring 2013 @BobRodes I'm not against the profession. I'm against the misuse of the title Engineer (regardless of the field)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere it was desk side support, but that's a rather specific name for the company I was working at.

Comment: @JustDoIt Your "misuse" is another's use.  A software engineer engineers software, hence the term.  You have yet to back up your statement that you "need the proper accreditation to be called an engineer."  That said, the term "engineer" has been applied to various IT disciplines for years without complaint (Microsoft Certified System Engineer, for example).  If various standards boards want to include software engineering as one of the various PE disciplines, and design tests for it, fine.  But show me the law that says I have to pass that test before I call myself a software engineer.

Comment: That said, the test outline looks like a good overview of the profession, and appears to contain stuff that any software engineer should know.  I have always supported the move towards formal licensing and degree programs for software engineering.  I just don't think it's there yet.  Also, there isn't any such exam for network/system engineers, which was the term that prompted your assertion in the first place.  So hey, nice to have, maybe in 10 years the engineers in the IT profession will have to take an exam or call themselves something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried one of the following terms?

- **[Technical Support](http://www.insitesupport.com/technical-support-representative-job-description/)**: "Under general supervision, in a 24/7 in-bound call center environment, Technical Support Representatives will provide technical and network problem resolution to end-users (customers) by performing a question diagnosis while guiding users through step-by-step solutions. Solutions include, but are not limited to, resolving username and password problems, uninstalling/reinstalling basic software applications, verifying proper hardware and software set up, power cycling equipment, assisting with navigating around application menus and troubleshooting email issues."
- **[Help Desk](http://www.americasjobexchange.com/help-desk-specialist-job-description)**: "Responsible for providing technical assistance and support related to computer systems, hardware, or software. Responds to queries, runs diagnostic programs, isolates problem, and determines and implements solution."
- **[Back-end Developer](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/29568/back-end-developer)**: "A back-end developer is a type of computer programmer who creates the logical back-end and core computational logic of a website, software or information system. The developer create components and features that are indirectly accessed by a user through a front-end application or system."

I hope this helps!

Comment: To be 100% honest, technically I bet "Help Desk" and "Tech Support" have definitions that fit the bill, but it's been my observation people look down on those titles and they are generally considered less advance than someone who's used VMware with clusters in large data centers etc.

Comment: If it fits it should be used, its a valid position which requires knowledge and experience. I've never seen anyone looking down on a tech support.

Comment: @JustDoIt I am glad to hear you never heard of people looking down on those positions. Where I used to work their was a lot of prejudice and office politics.

Answer (score 1):

So, you were essentially DevOps, as you said - I see development (Front-end), QA and infrastructure (VMWare, raid configuration) there. I'd definitely go with that.

> [DevOps (a clipped compound of "development" and "operations")](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi24qeWpYvMAhUBJg8KHar-AYEQFghIMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDevOps&usg=AFQjCNFJ92Q5EzqRhCqRDgyKnsK7Jd1AzQ&sig2=CfVFULk0FHJqwNndugM9Kg) is a culture, movement or practice that emphasizes the collaboration and communication of both software developers and other information-technology (IT) professionals while automating the process of software delivery and infrastructure changes.

You'll be fine with that